# Django warnings (Make sure every static file has a unique path)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, static, django-admin

What is the reason for this warnings? I get them during `docker-compose up` command.

```
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/LICENSE.txt'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/LICENSE'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
```

My INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py looks like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "adminlte3",
    "adminlte3_theme",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "rest_framework",
    "corsheaders",
    "django_extensions",
    "drf_standardized_errors",
    "user",
    "celery",
]
```

Statics:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.getcwd()

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

So, If I run `python manage.py findstatic`
I find a lot of duble path files.
For example,

```
C:\Users\irina\app-backend\django_env\Lib\site-packages\adminlte3_theme\static\admin\js\core.js
 C:\Users\irina\app-backend\django_env\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\core.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding

```
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --ignore admin
```

to my docker/bash/entrypoin.sh

I have no thougnts why

```
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --ignore \app_folder_name\static\admin
```

didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

adminlte3 intentionally overides django.contrib.admin templates by using the same static folder /admin/xyz so you get the warning when using collectstatic. The sequence in installed apps decides on which admin app is found first and which one is second and therefore ignored.

If necessary you can use the --ignore option to avoid affected files/paths:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

> Ignore files, directories, or paths matching this glob-style pattern. Use multiple times to ignore more. When specifying a path, always use forward slashes, even on Windows.

```
.. collectstatic --ignore PATTERN, -i PATTERN¶
```

or create  a custom ignore list in a subclass:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#customizing-the-ignored-pattern-list

> Customizing the ignored pattern list:¶
>
> The default ignored pattern list, ['CVS', '.*', '*~'], can be customized in a more persistent way than providing the --ignore command option at each collectstatic invocation. Provide a custom AppConfig class, override the ignore_patterns attribute of this class and replace 'django.contrib.staticfiles' with that class path in your INSTALLED_APPS setting:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.apps import StaticFilesConfig

class MyStaticFilesConfig(StaticFilesConfig):
    ignore_patterns = [...]  # your custom ignore list
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I solve this problem, because theese warnings slow down the start of the application very much.

Comment: see updated answer above. Are you sure it is the warnings that slow down the process? Question is also why you need to run collectstatic at every start of application. Maybe you can avoid that/do it only once at deployment or is there a specific reason?

Comment: The project starts with docker-compose and my team lead doesn't like the situation with these warnings. Adding adminlte3 to the project was my assignment. I don't have much experience in this, unfortunately. I'm trying to add python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --ignore /app_folder/static/admin in docker/entrypoint.sh, but I have no success.

Comment: -- ignore with the filename(!) does not change anything?

Comment: the hard way would be before the collectstatic to delete the files in the virt.env-> admin->static folder ... sorry I do not have the precise path at hand